# CSS Animations - Showing and Hiding a Panel

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to create a panel that is similar in behavior to an [offcanvas panel](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas). Except, I do not want my panel to push my other content. Instead, I want my panel to basically slide in, on top of, and maybe even cover my content. I still want the panel to take up the full height of the container.

In an attempt to implement this, I've created this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns1756ky/1/). In it, you'll notice that I have a "toggle" button along with two CSS classes. These classes are supposed to implement the slide effect that I'm seeking. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. At this time, my CSS looks like this:

```
#side-panel {
    height:100%; 
    width:250px; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    right:0;
}

.panel-hide {
    right:250px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.panel-show {
    right:0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with my CSS, or if its something else though. In my opinion, my CSS animations look correct. However, I clearly have something incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ns1756ky/2/

1- Your javascript is wrong, you id is not sidePanel is side-panel;

2- Your css #sidePanel{} is overriding .panel-hide and .panel-show because CSS selectors using id has more importance than class

3 - Remove your class before you Add another class

```
var currentState = 'show';
window.toggle_click = function() {
  if (currentState === 'show') {
  $('#side-panel').removeClass('panel-show');
    currentState = 'hide';
  } else {
  $('#side-panel').removeClass('panel-hide');
    currentState = 'show';
  }
  $('#side-panel').addClass('panel-'+currentState);
}



.panel-hide {
    right:250px !important;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
    transition: 0.5s ease !important;
}

.panel-show {
    right:0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
    transition: 0.5s ease !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this with much lesser code. Use .toggleClass() function that's already built in jQuery. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns1756ky/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:100%;">
  <div id="content-area" style="height:100%;">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          Hello
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="content-wrapper" style="background-color:beige; height:100%;">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%;">
        Welcome
        <br />
        <p>
          This is some paragraph of text. The purpose of this text is to serve as a visual indicator that the panel is sliding on top of the content instead of pushing it around.
        </p>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary">toggle</button>
      </div>
      <div id="side-panel">
        <h3>Info</h3>
        <p>
          Here are some details that I need to share. This is basically an informational paragraph. The user can show or hide this information when they click the "toggle" button.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#side-panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
  transition: 0.5s ease !important;
}

.panel-hide {
  right: 250px !important;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease !important;
  transition: 0.5s ease !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#side-panel").toggleClass("panel-hide")
})
```

Comment: @jquery-mobile  Can I know why did you down vote the answer?